# Having difficulty bypassing view controller in stack when pushing view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am working on an app where I have three view controllers in sequence, ViewControllerA, ViewControllerB, and ViewControllerC.  Under certain circumstances, I need the user to go from ViewControllerA directly to ViewControllerC, but unfortunately, in doing so, during the transition to ViewControllerC, ViewControllerB briefly appears on screen, which I do not want.

Here is the code that I am working with:

Inside VCA:

```
ViewControllerB *vcB = [ViewControllerB new];
    ViewControllerC *vcC = [ViewControllerC new];
    vcB.rootViewController = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcC animated:YES];
```

As I mentioned above, the above code is happening inside ViewControllerA, and I am able to get to ViewControllerC, the problem is that unfortunately, ViewControllerB is displayed momentarily during the transition.  What is it I am doing wrong, what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Here's some nearly-correct-pseudocode

```
NSMutableArray *vcStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[vcStack addObject:vcB];
[vcStack addObject:vcC];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcStack animated:YES];
```

Obviously if you don't want the existing view stack, you can just throw it away and make your own array, however that will probably cause glitches with the animation.

Check out the docs for UINavigationController for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:

Comment: Hi Matt, and thanks very much for your solution.  Can you please explain why your solution works?  My question is, isn't the current stack the same as the one you are creating (i.e. vcStack), so why does this work, and using the previous stack does not?

Comment: Hi syedfa - the reason we create vcStack is because you can't directly modify the view stack because self.navigationController.viewControllers is read-only. So, you have to copy the pointers into a mutable array, do the modifications (in this one, adding the two VCs) and then set the entire stack in one shot. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not really.  I guess my question is, why modify the stack at all?  Why is that the problem, especially when we're inserting the two view controllers in the exact same order?

Comment: The way UINavigationController is architected, just using pushViewController:animated: needs to complete the first call the entire way through before the second one starts. This is more apparent on iOS8 because in iOS8 Apple changed/added more hooks into the push process, such that now you can modify and change animations and gestures that handle pushing and popping. So, to get around that, and only show 1 push animation for two VCs, we have to modify the stack, and then commit the changes in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can push `vcC`, and, once `vcC` is fully on the screen, quietly modify the stack to insert `vcB` before `vcA`.

```
ViewControllerB *vcB = [ViewControllerB new];
ViewControllerC *vcC = [ViewControllerC new];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcC animated:YES];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    NSInteger indexOfC = [viewControllers indexOfObject:vcC];
    [viewControllers insertObject:vcB atIndex:indexOfC];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to jump directly from A to C?

then just use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcC animated:YES];`

there's no need to push B also...or you need to keep that order?

Comment: If the user decides to press the back button on C, then yes, the user should be taken to B.  The skip is in going forwards, not backwards.

Comment: [self.navigationController addChildViewController:vcB] then push to C

Comment: Would this go before the line in your answer?  So it would be:[self.navigationController addChildViewController:vcB]; then [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcC animated:YES]; ?

Comment: I tried it, and unfortunately I am not moving at all from vcA.  I am calling the block of code, but nothing is happening.